# Enable Button once all EditText Fields are not empty

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have nine EditText fields that i am using TextWatcher, what i am hoping to get working is if All nine EditText fields are filled enable the Button if not Disable,

I have the Button disabled in OnCreate so when the program first runs the button is Disabled but once if i enter a number into one Edit Text field the button becomes enabled, even if the other eight fields are empty, also once i remove all Text from all fields the button is still enabled.

```
EditText T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9;
//    Button buttonClear;
Button ButtonScore;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

    T1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    T2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
    T3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText4);
    T4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText5);
    T5 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText6);
    T6 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText7);
    T7 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText8);
    T8 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText9);
    T9 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText10);
    ButtonScore = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonScore);
    ButtonScore.setEnabled(false);

    T1.addTextChangedListener(watcher);
    T2.addTextChangedListener(watcher);
    T3.addTextChangedListener(watcher);
    T4.addTextChangedListener(watcher);
    T5.addTextChangedListener(watcher);
    T6.addTextChangedListener(watcher);
    T7.addTextChangedListener(watcher);
    T8.addTextChangedListener(watcher);
    T9.addTextChangedListener(watcher);

    //updateButtonScore();
}

private final TextWatcher watcher = new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after)
    { }
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)
    {}
    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        if (T1.getText().toString().length() == 0 && T2.getText().toString().length() == 0 &&
                T3.getText().toString().length() == 0 && T4.getText().toString().length() == 0 &&
                T5.toString().trim().length() == 0 && T6.getText().toString().length() == 0 &&
                T7.getText().toString().length() == 0 && T8.getText().toString().length() == 0 &&
                T9.getText().toString().length() == 0) {
            ButtonScore.setEnabled(false);
        } else {
            ButtonScore.setEnabled(true);
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Your logic is flawed"

Since you want to disable the button if any one of the `EditText`-fields are empty, you should check them with OR (`||`) instead of AND (`&&`). If you use AND, the button will only be disabled if **all** the `EditText`s are empty *at the same time*.

You also have a bug in your code: `T5.toString().trim().length()`.
`T5.toString()` is a textual representation of the `EditText`, and should never be empty, this coupled with the usage of AND will lead to the condition never beeing true.

Comment: I missed the || and .trim, i removed them and it is now working, it being a while since i worked with java.

Answer (score 0):

This is normal, look at your condition.

if I have at least **ONE** field not empty, I pass into the else condition and button comes enable.

If you wanna have all field not empty, revert your condition process :

```
if(one of all field is empty) {
   button remains enable false
} else {
  button comes enable
}
```